# Bazel build Android Test Apk

Tags: android, bazel

I'm currently trying to build both apks from the Android application through bazel.

I have no issue building the original apk, but the test apk is more troublesome. Whenever I build it, it builds as a normal apk.

Is there anything specific you have to do to build the test apk?

here is my build.BAZEL

```
android_binary(
    name = "android_canary",
    custom_package = "my.test.app",
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["main/res/**"]),
    deps = [":android_canary_lib"],
)

android_library(
    name = "android_canary_lib",
    custom_package = "my.test.app",
    srcs = glob(["main/*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["main/res/**"]),
    exports = [
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:28.0.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:aar:1.1.3"),
    ],
)

android_binary(
    name = "android_canary_test",
    instruments = ":android_canary",
    custom_package = "my.test.app.test",
    manifest = "AndroidTestManifest.xml",
    deps = [":android_canary_test_lib"],
)

android_library(
    name = "android_canary_test_lib",
    custom_package = "my.test.app.test",
    srcs = glob(["test/*.java"]),
    deps = [
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test:runner:aar:1.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test:monitor:aar:1.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test:rules:aar:1.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test:core:aar:1.0.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:aar:3.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:aar:2.2.0"),
        "@junit_junit//jar",
        ":android_canary_lib",
    ],
)
```

Comment: A test APK is a normal APK, but with test classes, and a manifest that contains an <instrumentation> tag containing android:targetPackage and android:name elements. Could you explain more on what you're expecting?

Comment: Hi yes. I do get the test APK, but when I attempt to install both apks and run the tests using `adb shell am instrument -w -r -e class 'com.xxx.xxx' com.xxx.xxx.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xx" on path: DexPathList[

I have tried also adding `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication` to the `application` under manifest name.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please [open an issue on the Bazel repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) with a reproducible example, thank you!